# use dynamic variable for google api http request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps-api-3

The form is set up to take user input which is being collected into a the address var.
Using jQuery to serialize address per url requirements. [jquery serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) 
Using getJSON to send the request to google geocode api.
Using a for in loop within a for loop to run through the results.
Finally, accessing the JSON results.

Question: Why am I getting `undefined` as result?

Code:

```
$(function() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    address += " "+document.getElementById('street_add').value;
    address += " "+document.getElementById('city').value;
    address += " "+document.getElementById('state').value;
    address += " "+document.getElementById('postcode').value;   

    $('#clickme').click(function() {
        var strAddress = $( "address" ).serialize();
        // data is an object containing info also called a map key/values
        $.getJSON("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=strAddress&sensor=false", function( data ) {
            for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
                for (key in data.results[i]) {
                    var mystring = data.results[0].formatted_address;
                    var mylat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                    var mylng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                } 
            }

            $("<ul/>", {
                "class": "zombies",
                html: document.write(mystring,'<hr />', mylat, '<hr />', mylng),
            }).appendTo( "body" ); 
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to append the value of `address` to the url string.

Secondly, you are assigning the return value of `document.write` to the `html` property of the new `ul` element. `document.write` does not return anything, hence you are seeing `undefined`.

Also, you are looping through `data.results` but for every iteration only retrieve the first item hence the `for` is redundant. Try this instead.

```
$.getJSON("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + strAddress + "&sensor=false", function( data ) {
    var mystring = data.results[0].formatted_address;
    var mylat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    var mylng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

    $("<ul/>", {
        "class": "zombies",
        html: mystring + '<hr />' +  mylat + '<hr />' + mylng),
    }).appendTo("body"); 
});
```